# ¿Cual es realmente la diferencia entre npm y npx?

Tags: npm, línea-de-comandos

Tengo entendido que npm **instala** un paquete y que npx **ejecuta** un paquete, pero ¿que diferencia exacta hay entre estos dos comandos?¿Que cosas hacen diferentes uno de otro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

veras la respuesta es sencilla.
NPM te permite instalar una dependencia de manera "normal", es decir, instalarla en el sistema para utilizarla o de manera global en el servidor. Por otra parte, con NPX puedes usar la dependecia sin instalarla localmente, (en ./node_modules/).
Imaginate un ejemplo, instalas un paquete con npm `npm v create-react-app` pero quieres probar otra version de `create-react-app`, pues usarias `npx create-react-app@next sandbox` (con `next` instalas la siguiente version, en este caso en el directorio `sandbox`).
Si navegas a la carpeta sandbox y corres la aplicacion (`npm start`), estaras usando la siguiente version de `create-react-app`. Entonces podemos afirmar que NPX te va a permitir ahorrarte todos los paquetes que instalas y despues no usas, ya que solo quieres probarlos

Comment: He encontrado este link de freeCodeCamp -> https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/npm-vs-npx-cual-es-la-diferencia/ que me ayudo a entenderlo en su momento, te lo dejo por aqui por si te vale de algo. Un saludo